# How to use BeginExecuteReader with an async WCF method

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I am trying to use BeginExecuteReader method of ADO.Net in an asyn WCF method, but not able to get it.

I have the following contract and service code. I cannot understand how do I fill in the details for callback method in the begin method of service. **Any help would be greatly appreciated since I cannot find any examples on the web or any documentation on MSDN for this.** Even some link to sample code would help since I am TOTALLY confused with how to do this.

**Contract code:**

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = ServiceConstants.ServiceContractNamespace,
    Name = ServiceConstants.ServiceName)]
    public interface IAsyncOrderService
    {
       [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]
       IAsyncResult BeginGetProducts(string vendorId, AsyncCallback callback,
                                                object state);

       List<Product> EndGetProducts(IAsyncResult result);
    }
```

**The service code is:**

```
    public IAsyncResult BeginGetProducts(string vendorId, AsyncCallback cb, object s)
    {
        DocumentsSummaryByProgram summary = null;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn1"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;


        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetProducts", conn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendorId", sqlCmd);

        conn.Open();

        return sqlCmd.BeginExecuteReader(cb, vendorId);
    }

    public List<Product> EndGetProducts(IAsyncResult r)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        SqlCommand cmd = r.AsyncState as SqlCommand;
        if (cmd != null)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.EndExecuteReader(r);
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //do your processing here and populate products collection object
            }
        }

        return products;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1 :**  This **seems like** an impossible task.  Microsoft should have provided   examples to show how ADO.Net async methods are called from WCF in async manner, since this would be useful for many apps out there that want to be scalable.

**UPDATE 2:** I have provided a detailed answer to my question, after I was able to successfully implement async pattern in WCF. Please look at the answer in a separate post below.

Comment: You "update" section is a highly inaccurate conclusion. Why do you believe that's true?

Comment: Sorry. I was hitting a roadblock constantly. But I was able to get it to work today. So, its no more impossible. But I still think there is inadequate documentation of how to use WCF async pattern on WCF side with ADO.Net async data methods. This area is very, very useful for customer-facing web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing a separate post to answer my question, since it's quite a long answer. I hope it helps others quickly implement async pattern in their WCF.
The points that I was missing when implementing async pattern in WCF, are as below. Without these, I was either getting a hung WCF problem saying 'Connecting...' or operation was aborted/canceled error message at WCF level. In my solution below, I have not discussed exception handling in async pattern on WCF side in order to keep it simple.

- **Do not invoke the EndGetProducts method of WCF by your code** like calling it by using delagateInstance.Invoke or any other way. In async pattern, all you need to do is call the client-side callback, when your long async operation is complete, which will result in your client-side callback being called which in turn will call the WCF EndGetProduct method ( example: cb(asyncResult1) where cb is the callback delegate instance passed by the client-side code calling this WCF). *I was trying to call the EndGetProducts WCF method by using Invoke, which is wrong.* Even when client-side is passing nothing for client callback, this should still be done to invoke the End method in WCF.
- **Do not return the asyncresult you get from ADO.Net async begindatareader method, from BeginGetProducts method**, since it needs to be the same AsyncResult that is in the context of client's call to WCF. This means you must include the client-side callback and the client-side state object in the AsyncResult that your BeginGetProducts will return, even when client-side is passing nothing for these. *I was returning the AsyncResult of ADO.Net async method begindatareader from BeginGetProducts, which is wrong.*
- **When calling the client-side callback delegate instance from WCF, make sure you pass the AsyncResult that contains client-side context** that I have discussed in last bullet. Also, do this when your async operation is complete, which I do in the callback of beginexecutereader after I have created a List object.
- One last point to keep in mind is that **you must set sufficiently large timeouts at WCF and ADO.Net levels**, since your async operation might take quite a long time else you will get timeouts in WCF. For this, set the ADO.Net command timeout to 0 ( infinite timeout) or to an appropriate value, and for WCF you can include configuration like below.

  ```
  <binding name="legacyBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"    
  receiveTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
  ```

Now the code, which might appear lengthy, but my intention is to make it easy for others to implement async pattern in their WCF. It was quite difficult for me.

**WCF Contract**

```
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(string))]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetProducts(string vendorId, AsyncCallback cb, object s);
    //The End method must return the actual datatype you intend to return from 
    //your async WCF operation. Also, do not decorate the End method with 
    //OperationContract or any other attribute
    List<Product> EndGetProducts(IAsyncResult r);
```

**WCF Implementation**

```
       public IAsyncResult BeginGetProducts( string vendorId, AsyncCallback cb, object s)
    {

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ABC_sp_GetProducts", "Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=NorthwindNew;Integrated Security:true;asynchronous processing=true;"));
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendorId", vendorId);
        sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;//async operations can be long operations so set a long timeout

        //THIS ASYNRESULT MUST REFLECT THE CLIENT-SIDE STATE OBJECT, AND IT IS WHAT SHOULD FLOW THROUGH TO END METHOD of WCF.
        //THE CLIENT CALLBACK (PARAMETER 'cb') SHOULD BE INVOKED USING THIS ASYNCRESULT, ELSE YOUR WCH WILL HANG OR YOUR WCF WILL GET ABORTED AUTOMATICALLY.
        AsyncResult<FinalDataForDocumentsSummary> asyncResult1 = new AsyncResult<FinalDataForDocumentsSummary>(false, s);//this is the AsyncResult that should be used for any WCF-related method (not ADO.Net related)

        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback);//this is callback for ADO.Net async begindatareader  method


        sqlCmd.Connection.Open();

        //AsynResult below is for passing information to ADO.Net asyn callback
        AsyncResult<Product> cmdResult = new AsyncResult<Product>(false, new object[] {sqlCmd, cb,s});

        sqlCmd.BeginExecuteReader(HandleCallback, cmdResult);


         return asyncResult1;//ALWAYS RETURN THE ASYNCRESULT INSTANTIATED FROM CLIENT PARAMETER OF STATE OBJECT. FOR DATAREADER CREATE ANOTHER ASYNCRESULT THAT HAS COMMAND OBJECT INSIDE IT.
    }


     /// <summary>
     /// This is the callback on WCF side for begin data reader method.
     /// This is where you retrieve data, and put it into appropriate data objects to be returned to client.
     /// Once data has been put into these objects, mark this ASYNC operation as complete and invoke the
    ///  client callback by using 'cb(asyncResult1)'. Use the same asyncresult that contains the client passed state object.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="result"></param>
    public void HandleCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        List<Product> summaries = new List<Product>();
        Product product = null;

        //THIS ASYNCRESULT IS ONLY FOR DATAREADER ASYNC METHOD AND NOT TO BE USED WITH WCF, ELSE BE READY FOR WCF FAILING
        AsyncResult<Product> asyncResult = result.AsyncState as AsyncResult<Product>;

        object[] objects = asyncResult.AsyncState as object[];
        SqlCommand cmd = objects[0] as SqlCommand;
        AsyncCallback cb = objects[1] as AsyncCallback;
        object s = objects[2];
       //CREATE THE SAME ASYNCRESULT THAT WE HAD IN BEGIN METHOD THAT USES THE CLIENT PASSED STATE OBJECT
        AsyncResult<Product> asyncResult1 = new AsyncResult<Product>(false, s);


        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        if (cmd != null)
        {
            try
            {
                  dr = cmd.EndExecuteReader(result);
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    product = new Product(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1));
                    summaries.Add(summary);
                }


                dr.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

                //USE THE CORRECT ASYNCRESULT. WE NEED THE ASYNCRESULT THAT WE CREATED IN BEGIN METHOD OF WCF.
                asyncResult1.Data = new FinalDataForDocumentsSummary(count, summaries.OrderByDescending(x => x.CountOfOverDue).ToList());

            }
            finally
            {
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    dr.Close();
                }
                if (cmd.Connection != null)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
                }

                //USE THE CORRECT ASYNCRESULT. WE NEED THE ASYNCRESULT THAT WE CREATED IN BEGIN METHOD OF WCF
                asyncResult1.Complete();

                //THIS IS REQUIRED ELSE WCF WILL HANG. EVEN WHEN NO CALLBACK IS PASSED BY CLIENT,
                //YOU MUST EXECUTE THIS CODE. EXECUTE IT AFTER YOUR OPERATION HAS COMPLETED, 
                //SINCE THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE END METHOD IN WCF TO EXECUTE. 
                //DON'T TRY TO CALL THE WCF END METHOD BY YOUR CODE (like using delegateInstance.Invoke) SINCE THIS WILL HANDLE IT.
                cb(asyncResult1);

            }
        }


    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets automatically called by WCF if you include 'cb(asyncResult1)' in the reader's callback meethod, so don't try to call it by your code. 
    /// But always use 'cb(asyncResult1)' just after data has been successfully retrieved from database and operation is marked as complete.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="r"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Product> EndGetProducts(IAsyncResult r)
    {

       AsyncResult<Product> result = r as AsyncResult<Product>;


       // Wait until the AsyncResult object indicates the 
       // operation is complete, in case the client called the End method just after the Begin method.
        if (!result.CompletedSynchronously)
        {
            System.Threading.WaitHandle waitHandle = result.AsyncWaitHandle;
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        // Return the database query results in the Data field
        return result.Data;

    }
```

**Generic class for AsyncResult that is needed in async pattern**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;


class AsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
{
    private T data;
    private object state;
    private bool isCompleted = false;
    private AutoResetEvent waitHandle;
    private bool isSynchronous = false;

    public T Data
    {
        set { data = value; }
        get { return data; }
    }

    public AsyncResult(bool synchronous, object stateData)
    {
        isSynchronous = synchronous;
        state = stateData;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        isCompleted = true;
        ((AutoResetEvent)AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return state; }
    }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            if (waitHandle == null)
                waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            return waitHandle;
        }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isCompleted)
                return false;
            else
                return isSynchronous;
        }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return isCompleted; }
    }
}
```

**How to call this from client-side:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ABCService.ServiceClient sc = new ABCService.ServiceClient())
        {
           // List<ABCService.Product> products = sc.GetDocSummary("Vend1", null, false);//this is synchronous call from client
          sc.BeginGetProducts("Vend1",GetProductsCallback, sc);//this is asynchronous call from WCF

        }

    }

    protected void GetProductsCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        List<ABCService.Product> products = ((ABCService.ServiceClient)asyncResult.AsyncState).EndGetProducts(asyncResult);//this will call the WCF EndGetProducts method

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You never called opened your `SqlConnection`

```
conn.Open();
```

Also you created two `SqlConnection` objects:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn1"].ConnectionString);
```

and:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetProducts", new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VHA_EDM"].ConnectionString));
```

**Edit**

To add an async callback you would do:

```
var callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback);
sqlCmd.BeginExecuteReader(callback, command);
```

If you don't have any asynchronous code that you planned on running in between `BeginExecuteReader` and `EndExecuteReader` you are better off just using `ExecuteReader`.

**Edit 2**

The `AsyncCallback` delegate has the following signature:

```
public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
```

From within that delegate method you can `Invoke` your `EndGetProducts` method.

**Edit 3**

Here is an example of retrieving data using `BeginExecuteReader`:

```
public SqlCommand Command { get; set; }

public IAsyncResult BeginGetStuff()
{
    var connect = "[enter your connection string here]";
    // Note: Your connection string will need to contain:
    // Asynchronous Processing=true;

    var cn = new SqlConnection(connect);
    cn.Open();

    var cmd = new SqlCommand("[enter your stored proc name here]", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this.Command = cmd;

    return cmd.BeginExecuteReader();
}

public List<string> EndGetStuff(IAsyncResult r)
{
    var dr = this.Command.EndExecuteReader(r);
    var list = new List<string>();
    while (dr.Read())
        list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made your suggested changes but still there is some complexity that I am missing. My code will still not work, since I haven't defined the call back in Begin method. The question is how to define this callback, and how it connects with the End method?

Comment: The reason, why I need to do it in an async manner is because the query to get products for a vendor takes 15 to 30 seconds on our database server. There is no point in holding on to valuable threadpool thread for this long time.

Comment: How will the 'HandleCallback' look like in its signature, and how will the End method be automatically fired after the callback completes?

Comment: Would it be this.Invoke(EndGetRpoducts) ?

Comment: Where would you get the data from datareader - in callback or in End method? what would you set in callback method for final data to be returned by End method?

Comment: Although it doesn't really matter where you do it (you just need the callback and the EndGetProducts because they have different delegate signatures), I would probably load them in the callback -- populate the list, invoke the End method to return the values.

Comment: I tried your suggested approach of delegate1.BeginInvoke( result, null, null), where delegate1 is pointing to End method. I do enter the End method and it returns data, but I never get returned to client. It then timesout after 10 minutes. So it seems WCF doesn't return to client. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using the asynchronous BeginInvoke, which also requires an EndInvoke. Just use Invoke instead.

Comment: I tried what you said but its still just remains in a hung state, even though the end method does get called. I hope there was some useful documentation by Microsoft.

Comment: I think the problem is not with how to use BeginExecuteReader but with how WCF would use it in async pattern. So, I do understand how to use BegiExecuteReader in ASP.Net pages, but when it comes to async pattern in WCF, it fails.

Comment: I FINALLY GOT IT. There are some very important points that one must keep in mind when writing an async pattern WCF method. I will explain all this in detailed answer later today. None of the samples I found on the web even remotely mention these important points.

Comment: Good to hear. Looking forward to seeing your resolution.